# How to use Spring data neo4j-RX to support multiple labels in a node

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

Can some one help me on how to use Spring data neo4j-RX JPA to support multiple labels in a node.

Suppose I have a below node in neo4j database

```
(:Person:Male {name:"ABC"])
```

How to convert above node with multiple labels to equivalent entity in Java with  neo4j-RX JPA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define multiple labels in the `@Node` annotation on your entity.

For example:

```
@Node("Person","Male")
public class MalePerson {}
```

Another option is to use inheritance:

```
@Node
public class Person {}

@Node
public class Male extends Person {}
```

This would not apply to your use-case but I also add the third option here: Dynamic Labels

```
@Node
public class Person {
  @DynamicLabels
  private List<String> labels; // here you would add Male
}
```

On a side note: Spring Data Neo4j RX (or now Spring Data Neo4j 6) is not a JPA implementation.